# Trouble adding/merging multiple DataTables together with different row counts

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, merge, dataset

I currently have a process that creates a dataset for each year since 2012. Each dataset has 4 datatables. Datatable 1 from 2012 is the same structure as Datatable 1 from 2013, and the same as Datatable 1 from 2014.

I need to do the following (this is obviously not valid - just a representation):

```
DsTotals.Tables[0] = Ds2012.Tables[0] + Ds2013.Tables[0] + Ds2014.Tables[0];

DsTotals.Tables[1] = Ds2012.Tables[1] + Ds2013.Tables[1] + Ds2014.Tables[1];

DsTotals.Tables[2] = Ds2012.Tables[2] + Ds2013.Tables[2] + Ds2014.Tables[2];

etc.
```

I am currently achieving this like so:

```
Year = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
 while (2012 <= Year)
{
    var Main = new DataSet();
    var DsT = DataAccess.GetNumbers(ByReferral, Year.ToString());
    //gets table 1 for year
    var DsT1 = DataAccess.GetNumbers(BySource, Year.ToString());
    //gets table 2 for year
    var DsT2 = DataAccess.GetNumbers(ByMedium, Year.ToString());
    //gets table 3 for year
    var DsT3 = DataAccess.GetNumbers(ByCampaign, Year.ToString());
    //gets table 4 for year

        var TableNumber = 0;
        foreach (DataTable table in DsT.Tables)
        {
            var Copy = table.Copy();
            Copy.TableName = "Table" + TableNumber.ToString();
            Main.Tables.Add(Copy);
            TableNumber++;
        }
        foreach (DataTable table in DsT1.Tables)
        {
            var Copy = table.Copy();
            Copy.TableName = "Table" + TableNumber.ToString();
            Main.Tables.Add(Copy);
            TableNumber++;
        }
        foreach (DataTable table in DsT2.Tables)
        {
            var Copy = table.Copy();
            Copy.TableName = "Table" + TableNumber.ToString();
            Main.Tables.Add(Copy);
            TableNumber++;
        }
        foreach (DataTable table in DsT3.Tables)
        {
            var Copy = table.Copy();
            Copy.TableName = "Table" + TableNumber.ToString();
            Main.Tables.Add(Copy);
            TableNumber++;
        }
        Process.Ds = Main;
        //global DataSet Variable

    var GrandTotalData = AddUpData(DsT, DsT1, DsT2, DsT3, Process.Ds, Year);
    Year--;
}

private static DataSet AddUpData(DataSet DsT, DataSet Ds1, DataSet Ds2, DataSet Ds3, DataSet Ds, int Year)
{

    if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count < DsT.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 0, TableNumber: 0);
        }

    }
    else if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > DsT.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < DsT.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 0, TableNumber: 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < DsT.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 0, TableNumber: 0);
        }

    }

    if (Ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count < DsT.Tables[1].Rows.Count)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < Ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 1, TableNumber: 1);
        }
    }
    else if (Ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > DsT.Tables[1].Rows.Count)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < DsT.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 1, TableNumber: 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < DsT.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 1, TableNumber: 1);
        }

    }

    if (Ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count < DsT.Tables[2].Rows.Count)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < Ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 2, TableNumber: 2);
        }

    }
    else if (Ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > DsT.Tables[2].Rows.Count)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < DsT.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 2, TableNumber: 2);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < DsT.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Processful(i, DsT, TableInt: 2, TableNumber: 2);
        }

    }

        if (Ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count < Ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Processful(i, Ds1, TableInt: 3, TableNumber: 0);
            }
        }
        else if (Ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count > Ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Processful(i, Ds1, TableInt: 3, TableNumber: 0);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Processful(i, Ds1, TableInt: 3, TableNumber: 0);
            }

        }
```

And so on, this method does this for all 12 tables in the same way.

```
private static void Processful(int i, DataSet DsT, int TableInt = 50, int TableNumber = 50)
        {

                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][1] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][1].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][1].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][2] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][2].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][2].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][3] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][3].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][3].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][4] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][4].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][4].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][5] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][5].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][5].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][6] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][6].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][6].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][7] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][7].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][7].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][8] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][8].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][8].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][9] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][9].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][9].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][10] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][10].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][10].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][11] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][11].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][11].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][12] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][12].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][12].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][13] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][13].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][13].ToString())).ToString();
                    Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][14] = (Convert.ToDecimal(Process.Ds.Tables[TableInt].Rows[i][14].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(DsT.Tables[TableNumber].Rows[i][14].ToString())).ToString();

                }
```

The processful method just adds all the data to the Global DataSet Variable.

Now this approach does work, IF all tables have the same number of columns and the same rows. Luckily, my tables DO have the same number of columns. Column count is a constant. However, year to year, there is a divergent number of rows. So for table 0, it lists all the possible referral places ie: Google, Facebook, Blog etc. It does a similar thing for tables 1,2,3. BUT each year, or even month to month, another row might be added. So now table 0 for 2014 has 3 other referral types, or perhaps 3 new ones and 1 that is no longer there ie: Twitter, Pinterest, Bing are now in the rows but Blog is no longer a referral for this year.

I need a more robust way of adding the datatables together so that if one datatable has 30 rows and another has 15, it will add together the ones that match and leave the others alone. That way at the end, the Global Dataset variable will have totals for all of the years and will contain 4 tables in all. It will have all the referrals from 2012, 2013, 2014 etc in its table 0, but will only be adding to the numbers if that referral still exists.

All of the Total data is being written to a spreadsheet (this part is taken care of). So once it is all totaled up, it will update the rows accordingly in the spreadsheet and add any if necessary.

Here is a snapshot of what Table 0 from 2012 would look like (dummy data, actual schema):

```
    Source  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Average Median  Total
            8.0 8.0 4.0 4.0 22.03.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  4.3     2.5    51.0
    blog    2.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.4     0.0    5.0
   Facebook 13.05.0 12.015.064.08.0 14.00.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  10.9    6.5    131.0
    Forum   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 15.02.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  1.7     0.0    20.0
    Google  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0.1     0.0    1.0
```

continues like this and ends with (Median, average, total are under Source Column):

```
   Median   2   1   1    1   6   1   1   0   0   0   0   0    1       0.0   0.0
   Average  13. 5.8 6.8 5.7 23.2 5.8 5.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 5.5      0.0   0.0
   Total    245 40  122 103 417 105 96  0   0   0   0   0     0        0    0
```

Also of note, is that the DataTables are tables that have been pivoted in SQL (hence the above)